# Is there "skip weaving flag" in Maven? (exclude AspectJ)

Tags: performance, maven, aop, aspectj

I build our multi-project application with Maven(lots of pom.xml-s). We recently introduced AspectJ, however I suspect AspectJ contributes to performance problems. In order to be sure, I'd like to build the application this time without AspectJ and see how it performs. But I would not really like to remove all AspectJ related stuff from pom.xml, so it would be handy if there was some kind of flag or something that could exclude AspectJ from build. Is there any?
Update: this does not seem to have any effect: -Dmaven.aspectj.skip=true

Comment: Do you want to exclude a aspectJ plugin or the corresponding libraries?

Comment: What I want is to revert back to the time when aspectj was not included without the removal of the aspectj from pom.xml.

Comment: Have you tried the disabling of the AspectJ plugin as proposed below? Thereby the AspectJ compilter will no be activated during build.

Comment: sorry, other things had higher priority, but I'll give a try to your approach and if it works I'll mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable the aspectj-maven-plugin temporarily, you could add a profile to the parent pom.xml which deregisters the executions of the plugin (by assigning them to phase *none*). Could look like this (add your own execution IDs if you have some):

```
<profile>
    <id>noAspectJ</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

A simple maven cmd activates this:

```
mvn clean install -PnoAspectJ
```